# OpenJDK 1.8 High CPU usage on filesystem usage

Tags: java, netbeans

Since I switched to OpenJDK 1.8 (linux debian, openjdk version "1.8.0_242"), I encountered a lot of issue with filesystem usage.

The CPU has really high usage peaks, over 150%, by only browsing files in applications like netbeans (8 to 11) and every other java apps that reads directories contents, resulting in a system slowdown after a bit.

The problem seems to be not present in the Oracle JRE 1.8 bundled with old netbeans 8.2 (java version "1.8.0_101").

I attached a screenshot.
[Netbeans 11 cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3zUT.png)

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Run a profiler (e.g. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) it should be included with the JDK) and see if you can pinpoint the culprit and possibly find a bug report.

Comment: We have same issue with open jdk 9, any updates you have on this topic, we use windows 10